# web-pack error when ERROR in src/polyfills.ts(73,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'global'. [ng] src/polyfills.ts(73,17):

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I upgraded an Ionic 3 project to an Ionic 4 project. When starting the server with "ionic serve" I always get the above error.

I have tried multiple things such as:

1. in the `polyfills.ts` file,

   ```
   (window as any).process = {
     env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    };
   (window as any).global = window;
   (window as any).process = window;
   (window as any).process.browser = true;
   (window as any).process.version = '';
   (window as any).process.versions = {node: false};
   global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
   ```
2. add the `script`  tag in the head with defining global etc.

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Neither worked.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Do you have node definitions in your tsconfig?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your index.html

```
    <script>
        if (global === undefined) {
            var global = window;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tsconfig.json includes the following code:

```
{
```

"compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}

Not sure if this includes a node definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here again, more readable:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```